# Magento Enterprise set tax

Tags: magento

I am using Enterprise Magento and what I need to do is set the tax so that is a customer is making a purchase and shipping to OH they are charged tax. However if they are shipping to any other state I do not need to charge Tax.

I logged into the admin panel moved my mouse over system then clicked configuration then under the sales section clicked tax.

I then have Tax Class for shipping set to Taxable goods
I also have Tax Based On the drop down is set to shipping address. In the section that is labeled Default Tax Destination Calculation I have the default state set to Ohio and the default country set to United States

when I move my mouse over Sales -> Tax then click Manage Tax Rules. I have a Product tax class which is set to Taxable Goods

I am not sure where else needs to be edited so that when a customer fills in their shipping address if the state they choose is Ohio tax should then be display'ed/added to the price listing

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've found two of the three configuration points for Sales Tax:

- General Tax Settings in System > Configuration > Sales > Tax (done)
- Tax Zone Setup in Sales > Manage Tax Zones & Rates (not done)
- Tax Class in Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules (done, but should be revisited after zone setup)

I didn't see in your description that you've set up a tax zone for OH yet?
Basically, you've told the system to calculate tax based on the destination address (global settings), you need need to tell it about the zones in which you want to calculate tax (tax zones - in this case just OH), and then which item groups you want to have the zones apply to (tax class - in this case all items in your Taxable Goods class).

The full walkthrough on setting up Tax Zones is available in the Magento documentation here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-setup-taxes-step3